# issue in communicating between child and parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this parent component where I render my child Component and I need to pass the changed state from child component to parent Component .
Both parent and child Components are using redux .
I have this code sandbox where I had done the same
https://codesandbox.io/s/znx09l905x
.Is this issue arising because of invoolvment of redux or some other thing .I don't even see my props from parent in the child component which is super weird .
I am getting this error

```
  TypeError: _this.props.toLogin is not a function
```

Here is the code for the parent Component and child Component.

```
 class Login extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state={
         isLoading:false
     };
    console.log('this.props.history',this.props);

}
 toLogin =statefromchild=>{
     console.log(statefromchild);
     debugger
     this.setState({
         isLoading:statefromchild
     });
 }

  return (
       // code inside return

           <div className={classes.root}>

            <SocialLogin  urltoredirect={urltoredirect} toLogin={this.toLogin}/>
        </div>

        </div>

);
    export default connect(
        mapStateToProps,
       {redirectUrl})
        (withStyles(styles)(Login));

  code for child Component

          class SocialLogin extends Component{
              constructor(props){
              super(props);
              this.state={
                userData:"",
                 isLoading:false
                };
            }
 login(){ // this is fired on click of a button in this component
    this.setState({
        isLoading:true
    },
     this.passdatatoparent
  );
    window.FB.login(this.checkLoginState(), {scope: 'email'});
}
passdatatoparent = () => {
 console.log('this.props',this.props);
 debugger
  this.props && this.props.toLogin(this.state.isLoading);
 };

  export default connect(
       null,
     { loginUser }
   )(SocialLogin);
```

Comment: when you don't have time to format your code, why someone will bang his head with your code to understand what it is doing

Comment: Will do it now .

Comment: also, please add the whole files instead of snippets. I would be a bit concerned about your imports too, when solving the problem.